# How to update one of the table columns which is basically having Year i just need an incremental update

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

My table name is kanaja_postmeta and i have around 1000 rows where i want to change the meta_value column values from `2017-01-23 00:00:00` to `2018-01-23 00:00:00`,

I tried using the query

```
Update `kanaja_wp`.`kanaja_postmeta` set `meta_value` = Date_Add(YYYY,+1,`meta_value`);
```

but getting an error code 1064.

```css
<style type="text/css">
  .tg {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin: 0px auto;
  }
  
  .tg td {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg th {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: normal;
  }
  
  .tg .tg-yw4l {
    vertical-align: top
  }
</style>
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031e">meta_id</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">post_id</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">meta_key</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">meta_value</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">403723</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">131871</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">_EventStartDate</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-01-23,00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">404269</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">131881</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">_EventStartDate</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-01-03 00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">404485</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">131883</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">_EventStartDate</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-01-03 00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">405271</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">131885</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">_EventStartDate</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-12-20 00:00:00</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```
meta_id post_id meta_key meta_value

403723  131871  _EventStartDate 2017-01-23 00:00:00
404269  131881  _EventStartDate 2017-01-03 00:00:00
404485  131883  _EventStartDate 2017-01-03 00:00:00
405271  131885  _EventStartDate 2017-12-20 00:00:00
404695  131887  _EventStartDate 2017-01-04 00:00:00
```

I just want to change only the year 2017 to 2018 how can i do that.

Comment: I'd expect the update to look more like this (untested): `update kanaja_postmeta set meta_value = Date_Add(meta_value, interval 1 year) where year(meta_value) = 2017;` You might need a different WHERE clause. HTML and CSS has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Hey Mike Thank you very much. This is great and the solution works well, the only issue is that my table kanaja_postmeta have  around more than 1000 rows and i need to change the year of all the row. 
I have executed the below query which changes the year of one particular row. If i want to change the year for all rows,i should specify the date_add and meta_id each time in a query,which makes the query too long.
can u help out,so i can change only the year and the date and month format should be same for rest of the rows. And do I need to specify the WHERE clause and date each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query works fine and it fulfilled my requirement

```
UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta
SET meta_value = DATE_ADD(meta_value, INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
WHERE meta_key="_EventEndDateUTC";
```

It works for all row names both start and End date as well.

Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I used two mysql function in combination with each other. One to turn your specific date format into a unix timestamp and one function to return a proper datetime after adding a year to it.
Here is an example of how to add one year to a datetime

```
SELECT
  FROM_UNIXTIME(
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2017-01-23 00:00:00') + (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with below mysql query:

```
 UPDATE kanaja_wp.kanaja_postmeta SET meta_value = DATE_ADD('2017-01-23 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 YEAR) **WHERE ID =1**
```

But make sure that you add proper where condition.